# Nested jQuery each() calls between two select lists in Oracle APEX

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I'm not sure if this is correct. I basically have two select lists (or a shuttle system), where I can make a selection from the left shuttle/list and move it over to the right shuttle/list.

This is being done within Oracle APEX.

Using the right shuttle/list as my driving list, I want to loop through each option value in this list and check to see if this option already exists as an option value in the left shuttle/list, i.e. a loop within a loop. If so, remove it.

Now I'm using the the .each(function() call on both these select lists but based on my console.log messages, I never see any console.log messages from my list_elements_left list, only from the list_elements_right.

Code being used is this:

```
$("#list_elements_right > option").each(function() {
    var rightOption = this.value;
    console.log("R:"+rightOption);
    $("#list_elements_left > option").each(function() {
        var leftOption = this.value;
        console.log("L:"+leftOption);
        if (leftOption === rightOption){
            $("#list_elements_left option[value='"+rightOption+"']").remove();
        }
    })
})
```

I noticed that when I ran this code within the Chrome Dev tools console, it worked fine but when actually being run within Oracle APEX from a button click, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w0f8091b/1/

Comment: Share your HTML, Are you using `optgroup`?

Comment: @Satpal No I am not.